# reg exp for string and any numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string, it can be like `<!--someWord1-->`, or `<!--newWord1233123123-->` or `<!--thirdWord-->`. In comment can be any word, or word with any number. I try this reg exp `/[a-zA-Z1-9]+/` and it works fine but with some problem :) numbers like 10, 20 etc. Ok, think that `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/` will resolve it, but nope. `<!--someWord10-->` will find only someWord1. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: The 2nd one you tried should work. The fact that your accepted answer works means you've got something more going on that you didn't post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `/\w+/`. It will match letters and numbers (letters followed by numbers).

Comment: `_` included though. `\w` was intended to match valid variable names!

Answer (score 1):

Your strings look very regular, so why not make use of that

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
let re = /<!--([a-z]+\d*)-->/i;
'<!--someWord1-->'.match(re); // ["<!--someWord1-->", "someWord1"]
'<!--newWord1233123123-->'.match(re); // ["<!--newWord1233123123-->", "newWord1233123123"]
'<!--thirdWord-->'.match(re); // ["<!--thirdWord-->", "thirdWord"]
'<!--someWord10-->'.match(re); // ["<!--someWord10-->", "someWord10"]
```

Here `re` is more strict, so the following will not pass the test

```
'foo'.match(re); // null (missing HTML comment)
'foo1'.match(re); // null
'<!--foo'.match(re); // null (malformed HTML comment)
'foo-->'.match(re); // null

'<!--foo1bar-->'.match(re); // null (number not at end)
'<!-- foo -->'.match(re); // null (spaces, you could add these in using \s*)
```

Comment: You're right @ibrahimmahrir, editing (image will follow)

Comment: I'm new in regex, so can you please explain me whats different from `/<!--([a-z]+?\d*)-->/` and `/\w+/`. All are works fine for me

Comment: @YoroDiallo `\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. `+` means _one or more_. `\d` is equal to `[0-9]`. `*` means _zero or more_. `?`s change the greediness of a `+` or `*`, I didn't need to use a `?` here as `[a-z]` will never match a `\d`

Comment: but since the string will never contain `_`, a `\w` will suffice.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir don't want to make assumptions about unspecified behaviour, assuming _"foo should match"_ means _"not foo should not match"_

Comment: @Paul S. thx a lot for your explain, it's very helpful for me!